# What to do with a poorly stated question without an answer

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015624/get-value-of-selected-option-from-dynamically-loaded-content-jquery is quite a poor and broad question. After I asked for more information, some (semi random) jQuery code and a comment (stating that the problem is fixed) got added by the OP.

Assuming that the OP will abandon the question after this and never returns, this question is quite worthless, so I voted to close it. Since I am the only one, the vote will probably fade away over time and the question remains.

It this the correct approach, or should I bug a moderator asking to delete the question (which is in my opinion better than leaving it closed)?

Comment: I would also like to know what to do about poorly-stated questions that are getting all kinds of random answers because no one can understand it, and the questioner isn't helping.

Comment: Vote to close (and optionally flag) is the right choice. Deletion is not really appropriate here; the OP may come back, discover that he can't find his question anymore, and repost it. Closing gives the OP two days to come back and find out the actual status of his question. He also gets a link to the FAQ on his closed post; overall, it's a much more productive way to do things.

Comment: @Robert, Oh then I was a bit too hasty with my flag :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would vote-to-close AND flag a moderator if the question was without merit and had no answer, therefore no one would ever be helped by it.

(Voted to Close as too localized for that specific one, but didn't flag, since I wasn't sure of the subject enough to be sure of my flag).

Comment: That was what I just did, I could not bear the existence in that question anymore... ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the question doesn't mean any sense, or there isn't enough information for a meaningful answer, vote to close as “not a real question”.

Users with [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) have access to a page with a list of questions with pending close votes. It's likely that four more people will pile onto your vote.

If the question is egregiously bad, flag it as “very low quality”. This makes the question come up in another list that's seen by both users with 10k reputation and moderators. Again, most of the time, users with 10k reputation will pile on and quickly close the question.

Normally, a closed question remains on the site for a couple of days. This allows the asker to find that the question is closed and why (if the question is deleted, the asker won't be able to find it). It also allows the closure to be disputed. If there is a pressing need to delete the question (for example because it's spam, or because it contains information that should have remained confidential), flag it to hasten the process — but this is for exceptional cases, not for merely low-quality questions.